# Editing the Backend Uploader

Tags: admin, uploads

So my boss wants me to edit the backend of his WP site so that he can add a video link from a site called vzaar, which hosts all of our content. I need to know where in the backend I can edit to allow this to happen. I dont need to know how to do it, just need to know what I'm looking for.

Here is an image of where he wants the option

[image]

Comment: Just use a plugin that extends the oEmbed list with [the vzaar provider](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress+embed+vzaar&aq=f&oq=wordpress+embed+vzaar&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0l2j60l2.3215&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Post Meta Box / Custom Field. Try find it in functions files inside the THEME folder.

Comment: can I edit this from the wp-admin area, or do I need to use the server ftp client?

Comment: This need to be edit directly in the theme files, which hold the codes. So you need FTP client

Comment: Ok, is this recommended? What happens if the theme gets updated? Do I lose my changes?

Comment: Not recommended, if theme updated, you lose your changes. So better to backup your changes. As I know there is no other way to add functionality to theme without editing it's functions files

Comment: Oh bummer. I'll have to talk to my boss about this whole wordpress situation. Probably not the right the solution for our site. Thanks.

Comment: Even thought you ask the theme developer to add this functionality only for your theme, the theme developer will also need to change the code every time the theme is updated.

Comment: @bwheeler96 it really depends on how the particular theme is built, but it may be possible to simply [remove the meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) and [add your own](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) via a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) which duplicates the functionality while adding your own custom options. this way your changes aren't overwritten in a theme update.